# C++: Why can my object not use the setter of another object, but can use the getter?

Tags: c++, class, object, setter, getter

I have two classes in my code: CoinManager, which has one function only, which is to add a specific amount of coins to a specific Player object, and the Player class.

```
class Player{
public:
    void addCoins(int amount){
        coins+=amount;
    }
    int getCoins(){
        return coins;
    }
private:
    int coins = 0;
}
class CoinManager{
public:
    void freeCoins(Player user, int amount){
        user.addCoins(amount);
    }
}
int main(){
    Player i;
    CoinManager CM;
    i.addCoins(20); //this works
    CM.freeCoins(i, 20); //this doesn't work
}
```

With the CoinManager class I can have a getter function of Player's coins like this:

```
int getCoins(Player user){
    return user.getCoins();
}
```

But I cannot use the *freeCoins(Player i, int amount);* function. No error comes up, simply the function does not change the value of coins in the Player object.

Comment: You're passing a copy of `i` to the `freeCoins` method. You'll need to pass a pointer or reference.

Comment: Ah, alright. Could you link me to some pointer article? I'm only a beginner in C++.

Comment: @user5749558 You can read the C++ tag wiki here, which links many useful things. http://stackoverflow.com/tags/c%2b%2b/info

Comment: Also, dull as it sounds, check google. This is a VERY common stumbling point for new programmers, and there are bazillion articles out there covering the subject. There's sure to be at least one that makes it "click" for you.

Comment: `void freeCoins(Player &user, int amount)`

Comment: Thank you, how can I close this question?

Comment: OP, the best way for this question to be closed would be for @Cornstalks to post his comment as answer so you can accept it and future readers can still learn from this question. (Rather than this question just being permanently deleted, which offers no help to future readers.)

Comment: For me, I like to think of pointers this way: every byte in memory has an "address" or ordering number. There's the first byte, the second byte, etc. Every variable you make, resides in some bytes out there. A "pointer" is just another variable (so it too takes up a few bytes of memory) which itself contains the address number for some byte in memory. If you know what data resides in that memory (for example, it's the first byte of an integer), then you can manipulate that data like another variable.

Comment: In C/C++, you can have a pointer to the first byte of anything you can store in a regular variable (yes, you can have a pointer to a pointer as well, just for kicks :)